# bootstrap placing item in middle

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am usign bootstrap in reactjs and trying to put a text in the middle of the screen but it doesn't work. can you please tell me what wrong i have done ?

```
<div className="h-100 d-flex align-self-center justify-content-center">
     <div className="alert alert-danger">I SHOULD BE CENTER</div>
</div>
```

[image]

can anyone help me why it is not working?

I have tried with both `align-items-cente` and `align-self-center`, and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

As @James already suggested, you should change `align-self-center` to `align-items-center`, but this is not enough. You also need to make some changes to your code.

```
<body className="vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div className="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div className="alert alert-danger">I AM CENTERED</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
body {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `align-items-center`. If I remember correctly you may need to make use of `flex-direction: column` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `align-items-center` instead of `align-self-center`

```
<div className="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
     <div className="alert alert-danger">I SHOULD BE CENTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried with both `align-items-cente` and `align-self-center`, and it doesnt work

Comment: Add width and height sizing classes `class="vw-100 vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"`